# Upgrading Visio 2000 to Visio 2007

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-visio

I have Microsoft Visio 2000 SR 1, and recently purchased Microsoft Office Visio Standard 2007 with the understanding (supported by the product info and some other research) that I'd be able to upgrade.  However, when I install 2007, it tells me it can't find a previous install of Visio, but... it's right there!  Here's the exact message:

"Setup can't find a version of Microsoft Office on your computer.

If Office is installed on a disk or network share, click the browse button to select the appropriate disk or share... (etc.)"

No matter which directory or drive I pick (various Office installs, the old Visio install, various subdirectories) it gives the following message:

"The path you have chosen does not point at a qualifying upgradeable product.  Click 'Retry' to try again or 'Cancel' to quit setup."

Any ideas?  This is a legit copy of Visio 2007 (purchased from Amazon) and the copy of Visio 2000 is legit as well.  I'm not sure what exactly the installer is looking for that it would consider a "qualifying upgradeable product".  A specific file?

Answer (score 1):

You CAN do it with Visio2000:  just choose \INSTALL\BIN

Answer (score 0):

They key is this portion of the message:

> [...]qualifying upgradeable product[...]

I'd wager that qualifying versions probably don't extend that far back. I checked [this Office 2007 page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/products/FX101754511033.aspx) and it appears to agree that your version it too old:

> Microsoft Visio Standard 2000–2002;
>   Microsoft Office Visio Standard 2003;
>   Visio Professional 2000, 2002, and
>   2003.

**Edit.** Whoops! I see your version is indeed listed! Time to call Microsoft :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you still have the install media (probably CD in 2000) point the new installer to that instead. You should be able to take out the new CD/DVD while you do this with no problem.

Failing this (eg if you don't have the CD), a call to MS might help resolve this.